# Detect background image attribute, then background image ratio, add relevant classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use jquery to detect if an image background has been set in the style attribute of an elements, then if present determine the aspect ration of the image and add relevant classes to the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/2urn/9ydHG/37/

```
<article class="listing-article" style="background-image:
url('http://placehold.it/600x350/ff6600/fff');">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="article-summary">
<h2 class="post-title post">Horizontal Background</h2>
<section class="article-excerpt">
<h3 class="subhead">Subhead</h3> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
</section>
</div>
</article>
```

I have referenced some related stack articles in the js window of the fiddle but the code is too complex for my level.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the jQuery to do such thing. Commented the sections for easy read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Loop through all the articles.
    $('.listing-article').each(function() {
        var $article = $(this);

        // Check if they have a background image.
        if ($article.css('background-image') !== 'none') {
            $article.addClass('bg-img');

            // Extract background url.
            var articleBG = $article.css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','');

            // Load up the image to get its dimension.
            $('<img src="'+ articleBG +'"/>').load(function(){
                var imgWidth = this.width;
                var imgHeight = this.height;


                if (imgWidth === imgHeight) {
                    $article.addClass('bg-square');
                }
                else if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
                    $article.addClass('bg-horizontal');
                }
                else {
                    $article.addClass('bg-vertical');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $article.addClass('bg-none');
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ydHG/38/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
var backgroundImg = $('article.listing-article').css("background-image");

if (typeof(backgroundImg) != "undefined") {
    // background image present, do stuff here
}
```